# Store reactiveValue to a dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I have this app that filters `names` from an existing data and prints out the `selection`.

The idea of it is that the user can run a script over the `selection` (in this case, names) and return an analyses page, with graphs and other values.

I'm having two problems:

**SOLVED - 1. How to store reactiveValue to DF**

I found out that if i use

```
selection <<- values$df
```

instead of

```
selection <- values$df
```

it would do the trick. But i still need to work on other stuff.

**2. Call an R script that will create the analyses**

let's say i have this `"function.r"` that returns a page with some summary on the data, like graphs and so... how will ir reload the whole page to the analyses?

i've tried calling `source("function.r")` to do so but it wouldn't redirect.

I hope i've made myself clear and thanks in advance because i'm in a kind of a hurry!
=)

**CODE**

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)

names <- c("Adam", "Smith", "Frank")
id <- c(1234, 4321, 1111)
data <- data.table(names, id)
rm(names, id)

ui <- fluidPage(      
  fluidRow(
    column(8, 
           h2("Create Analyses"),
           selectInput(inputId = "names", label = "Search names", 
                       choices = data$names, multiple = TRUE),
           actionButton("add","Add"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(12, 
           h2("Analyses"),
           dataTableOutput("tabela"),
           actionButton("genanalyses","Generate Analyses"))
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- df
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    values$df <- data[names %in% input$names]
selection <<- values$df
  })

  output$tabela <- renderDataTable({return(values$df)})

  observeEvent(input$genanalyses, {
    source("function.r")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't seem to workout"? Did you get an error? Did you get an unexpected result?

Comment: i'm going to update it, just a sec

Comment: before i do it... it didn't recognize the `selection`. i've found now that if i use `selection <<- values$df` it will work, but i still can't figure out how to redirect it to the analyses page... =/